# Using 's' at the end of plural form, when the name is formed of two nouns

Tags: plural-forms

For example lets consider the name 'file system'. It consists of 2 nouns. Now, lets assume I want to use it in plural form. Which one of the following sentences is correct?

> I have 5 file systems installed.

> I have 5 files systems installed.

Is it like always one of them is valid, or maybe it depends on the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context is not relevant. The correct version is always this:

> I have 5 file systems installed.

The rule is that only one word of a compound noun gets a plural ending. In most cases, it is the last word. In a few rare cases, where the final word modifies the previous noun, the noun gets modified:

> courts martial
> *not*
> *court martials

where **court** is the noun, and **martial** identifies the *kind* of **court.** As I said, these cases are rare. As far as I know, everyone memorizes them individually.

Comment: "everyone memorizes them individually"... Actually most people forget about them, which is why we get "secretary generals" and  "poet laureates"